# Java - validate strings between a range of letters

Tags: java, validation, loops

I have written a simple test program for a larger program, where I need to validate the String by a range of letters from a through to g.

The below test program should ask for a letter, then if within range of a-g print an acceptance message, else say 'oops' and ask again.

Comment: Are you sure this code compile? [if (input == maxValue || minValue)]

Comment: Note for future questions: "The code has an error whilst checking for the range (a-g)" is way too unspecific. If you get an error then post as much information as you have (which error, where, what happens but what would you expect etc.).

Comment: So you need to "where I need to validate the String" or a character . Is the input aga or just a?

Answer (score 1):

Try this Code:

```
public static void main(String... params) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    Character minValue = 'a';
    Character maxValue = 'g';
    while (true) {
        System.out.print("enter a char between a-g: ");
        Character input = s.nextLine().charAt(0);
        if (input >= minValue && input <= maxValue) {
            System.out.println("Ok");
        } else {
            System.out.println("oops");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a `char` from `String` using `charAt(index)`.

You can check if the `char` is withing given range using simple comparison like `c >= 'a' && c <= 'g'`.

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't think you should name your variable "a".

Aniways, I would validate my input like this:

```
a.compareTo(maxValue) >= 0 && a.compareTo(minValue) <= 0 && a.length == 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code:

import java.util.Scanner;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class StringValidation {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String a = null;
    char minValue = 'a';
    char maxValue = 'g';
    boolean loop = true;
    int i = 0;

    while (loop) {
        System.out.print("enter a char between a-g: ");
        a = input.nextLine();
        if ((int) minValue <= (int) a.charAt(i)) {
            if ((int) maxValue <= (int) a.charAt(i)) {
                System.out.println("Oops! ");
                System.out.print("enter a char between a-g: ");
                i++;
                input.nextLine();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Accepted");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    input.close();
}
```

}